# Площадь невыпуклого многоугольника

Tags: c++, массивы, вычислительная-геометрия

Задача: Многоугольник (необязательно выпуклый) задан на плоскости перечислением координат вершин в порядке обхода его границы. Определить площадь многоугольника.

Написал код для вычисления площади выпуклого многоугольника (да, с выделением памяти в куче). Как его можно переделать под вычисление площади невыпуклого многоугольника и вообще алгоритм определения: введенный многоугольник является выпуклым или нет?
(Если без разбивания многоугольника на фигуры никак, то напишите, пожалуйста, как его разбить и вычислить каждую фигуру отдельно)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace System;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    int y, x, c, i = 0;
    cout << "Кол-во углов ";
    cin >> c;
    int(*coor)[2];
    coor = new int[c][2];
    while (i != c)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            cout << "Введите координаты " << endl;
            cout << "По X ";
            cin >> x;
            cout << "По Y ";
            cin >> y;
            coor[i][j] = x;
            j = 1;
            coor[i][j] = y;
            j = 2;
        }
        i++;
    };
    i = 0;
    int t = i + 1;
    double sum, pl = 0;
    for (i; t!= c; i++)
    {
        sum = ((coor[i][0] + coor[t][0])*(coor[i][1] - coor[t][1])) / 2;
        pl = pl + sum;
        t++;
    }
    cout << "Площадь " << abs(pl) << endl;
    system("pause");
    delete[]coor;
}
```

Так выглядит эта же прога без массивов. Здесь все работает верно. Видимо неправильно интегрировал сюда динамический массив... Помогите, пожалуйста

```
int n, x, y, x1, x2, y1, y2;
    double sum = 0;
    cout << "Введите кол-во углов многоугольника: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Введите координаты вершины многоугольника: ";
    cin >> x >> y;
    x1 = x;
    y1 = y;
    for (int i = 0; i < (n - 1); i++) 
    {
        cout << "Введите координаты следующей вершины: ";
        cin >> x2 >> y2;
        sum = sum + (x1 + x2)*(y2 - y1);
        x1 = x2;
        y1 = y2;
    }
    sum = sum + (x + x2)*(y - y2);
    sum = abs(sum) / 2;
    cout << fixed << setprecision(3) << sum << endl;
```

Comment: Что такое `using namespace System;`???

Comment: Шаблон консольного приложения

Comment: `namespace System` - это элемент языка/платформы C++/CLI. При чем в этом вопросе C++/CLI? Какой язык вы хотите использовать: C++ или C++/CLI?

Comment: Ну по сути я создаю Консольное приложение CLR. Мне кажется это не играет особой роли...

Comment: У вас в коде нет ничего от CLI. И вы поставили на свой вопрос тэг `[c++]`, а не `[c++-cli]`. Поэтому я не вижу смысла в этом `using namespace System;`, которое только захламляет код.

Comment: Ну хорошо, я Вас услышал. Сам еще новичок, в таких моментах не особо разбираюсь...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в коде реализована какая-то совсем бессмысленная формула, никакого отношения ни какой площади не имеющая даже для выпуклых многоугольников.

Ваша формула как-будто отдаленно напоминает [формулу "шнуровки"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8_%D0%93%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0) для вычисления площади многоугольника. Формула "шнуровки" прекрасно работает для любого простого многоугольника. Никакого требования выпуклости многоугольника у этой формулы нет. Именно эта формула вам и нужна.

То есть: реализуйте правильную формулу. И помните, что в ней участвуют все ребра многоугольника, в том числе и ребро из последней вершины в первую.

---

Ваш "псевдо-цикл" `for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)` при вводе координат вообще поражает своей сюрреалистичностью. Зачем вы писали *цикл*, если никакого цикла вы там не собирались делать?

---

Ваш код "без массивов" - вариант корректной реализации формулы шнуровки.

Comment: Чтобы выделить память в куче для галочки (так как это требовалось в правилах решения этой задачи)

Comment: @llatibro: Не понял. На какой вопрос вы отвечаете?

Comment: Про псевдо-цикл

Comment: И для выпуклых многоугольников эта формула работает прекрасно

Comment: @llatibro: Ваш псевдо-цикл по `j` не имеет никакого отношения к динамической памяти. И еще раз: ваш псевдо-цикл по `j` - это вообще не цикл. Он делает только одну "итерацию". Зачем тогда цикл вообще?

Comment: Что касается "формула работает прекрасно" - не несите чепухи. Вот вам треугольник: `(10, 0), (2, 10), (0, 10)`. Посчитайте-ка его площадь вашей замечательной "формулой". Расскажите нам о результатах.

Comment: Да уж, согласен, только что попробовал другие значения и он считает неправильно, либо пишет что площадь 0. Забавно что мне в голову приходили только такие многоугольники с которыми она работает....

Comment: Без цикла не работает. Либо я не знаю как это сделать без него

Comment: добавил другую программу в описание вопроса, посмотрите. Буду рад если поможете

Comment: @llatibro: Ваша "другая программа" - вариант корректной реализации формулы шнуровки. Она работает правильно. Причем и на невыпуклых многоугольниках тоже.

Comment: Ну да... Может покажете как её переделать через массивы, пожалуйста?

Answer (score 0):

Решил следующим образом, все работает правильно, даже с невыпуклыми треугольниками. Спасибо за замечания, AnT.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    int c, i = 0;
    cout << "Кол-во углов ";
    cin >> c;
    int(*coor)[2];
    coor = new int[c][2];
    while (i != c)
    {
        cout << "Введите координаты " << endl;
        cout << "По X ";
        cin >> coor[i][0];
        cout << "По Y ";
        cin >> coor[i][1];
        i++;
    };
    double sum = 0;
    i = 0;
    int t = 1;
    while (t != c) 
    {
        sum = sum + (coor[i][0] + coor[t][0])*(coor[t][1] - coor[i][1]);
        t++;
        i++;
    }
    t = c - 1;
    i = 0;
    sum = sum + (coor[i][0] + coor[t][0])*(coor[i][1] - coor[t][1]);
    cout << "Площадь " << fixed << setprecision(3) << abs(sum) / 2 << endl;
    system("pause");
    delete[]coor;
}
```